# AppleScript - extract an email message as a MIME object

Tags: macos, applescript, mime, apple-mail

I have an AppleScript I wrote to do some parsing on Mail.app messages, however it seems I will need more powerful processing (specifically - separate a replied message from the original message it quotes) than what is provided by AppleScript (say, using Python's `email` package). Is it possible to get an email message as a MIME string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you meant, but here is how you can get the raw message text from a selection you've made in Mail.app which can than be processed with MIME tools to extract all the parts.

```
tell application "Mail"
    set msgs to selection
    if length of msgs is not 0 then
        repeat with msg in msgs

            set messageSource to source of msg

            set textFile to "/Users/harley/Desktop/foo.txt"

            set myFile to open for access textFile with write permission
            write messageSource to myFile
            close access myFile

        end repeat
    end if
end tell
```

And then here's a Python email example script that unpacks the message and writes out each MIME part to a separate file in a directory

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email-examples.html

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""Unpack a MIME message into a directory of files."""

import os
import sys
import email
import errno
import mimetypes

from argparse import ArgumentParser


def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description="""\
Unpack a MIME message into a directory of files.
""")
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--directory', required=True,
                        help="""Unpack the MIME message into the named
                        directory, which will be created if it doesn't already
                        exist.""")
    parser.add_argument('msgfile')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    with open(args.msgfile) as fp:
        msg = email.message_from_file(fp)

    try:
        os.mkdir(args.directory)
    except FileExistsError:
        pass

    counter = 1
    for part in msg.walk():
        # multipart/* are just containers
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue
        # Applications should really sanitize the given filename so that an
        # email message can't be used to overwrite important files
        filename = part.get_filename()
        if not filename:
            ext = mimetypes.guess_extension(part.get_content_type())
            if not ext:
                # Use a generic bag-of-bits extension
                ext = '.bin'
            filename = 'part-%03d%s' % (counter, ext)
        counter += 1
        with open(os.path.join(args.directory, filename), 'wb') as fp:
            fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So then if the unpack.py script is run on the AppleScript output...

```
python unpack.py -d OUTPUT ./foo.txt
```

You get a directory with the MIME parts separated. When I run this on a message which quotes an original message then the original message shows up in a separate part.